# getting SSLException while making RESTful call

Tags: java, web-services, rest

There is REST webservice is running on my machine and it is working fine while accessing from the browser but getting exception while accessing through REST call from java code running on the same machine. Please help me to resolve this. Try to put detailed code. Thanks!! 
Please do not mark this post as duplicate, i checked with other questions not found so similar one.
I'm trying with the below code...

```
TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }

            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }
        } };


        try {
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        } catch (KeyManagementException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


        HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier() {
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return true;
            }
        };


        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);


        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://17.91.15.84:8088/login");
        List<BasicNameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", "user1")); 
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "user1$"));
                    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }           
    }
```

and while running the same code on the same machine where the service is running, I end up with the below exception message..

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <17.91.15.84> != <My-PC>
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:220)
```

Comment: what version of `HttpClient` JAR are you using?

Comment: Is the certificate OK?

Comment: @Amogh: httpclient-4.0.jar

Comment: I am not so sure but `return null` in `getAcceptedIssuers()` is just a bypass of certificate checking. Just confirm by some expert.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the certificate is for the DNS. try instead of the IP-Adress the DNS-Name.

`HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://XXDNSXX:8088/login");`

Answer (score 0):

You have to change code as you want to `post` the request with the parameters but certificate bypass code is same for `HttpPost` as well as `HttpGet`

**`return null` in `getAcceptedIssuers()` is just a bypass of certificate checking.**

> ***Warning*** : Don’t try it at production environment, unless you have a very
>   solid reason to by pass all the certificate checking. Ans if yes, why
>   are you still using SSL connection? :)

Try this out :

```
@Test
        public void withTrustManeger() throws Exception {
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = buildhttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://url.url.com");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute( httpGet );

            HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    inputStream));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            inputStream.close();
            String jsonText = sb.toString();
            System.out.println(jsonText);
        }
```

`buildhttpClient()` function as follows :

```
private DefaultHttpClient buildhttpClient() throws Exception {
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sc.init(null, getTrustingManager(), new java.security.SecureRandom());

            SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLSocketFactory(sc);
            Scheme sch = new Scheme("https", 443, socketFactory);
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry().register(sch);
            return httpclient;
        }
```

Here `getTrustingManager()` is exactly same as your `trustAllCerts`.

Comment: it is just for development purpose only, so no problem with by passing. I tried with your code but still I'm getting... 

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match:

Comment: @Nani, then you should try for `setHostnameVerifier`, in `verify` method check for `host` name with your testing purpose `hostname` if it's equal then `return true` otherwise `false`

Answer (score 0):

I had faced a similar issue even when the certificate was very much valid. The system was running on jdk 1.7, when I had upgraded my jdk to 1.8, the issue was resolved.

This might not be the same case with everyone.